# What is the best way to find a specific position in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Working with Beautiful Soup 4 I have created some code that works to scrape online data from a webpage. In this instance I am trying to read data from a table, but only want it from a specific row in the table, in this instance the 4th row. I was wondering if there is an argument I could pass to the `.find()` argument that would ignore the first 3 instances of `tr` so that it only returns the fourth row.

What I attempted so far was:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
weather = soup.find_all('tr', limit=4)
```

and then I was just going to work with the last index in this list, however I was wondering if there was a better method to just take the 4th appearance of `tr`

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this will work

`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
weather = soup.find_all('tr')[3]`

as find_all returns a list and you can control it with index. So if you want the 4th row, use the 3 index and if the 5th row use 4 and so on...